# Error when using form.submit()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, extjs4.1

We are using `extjs and webapi(C#)` for our application. My form has a `fileupload` control. When we use `form.sumbit()` in extjs, it is not going to the success function.

**WebApi code:**

```
bool SaveData(Employee obj)
{
     return true;
}
```

**Extjs code:**

```
form.submit( {
               url: '../api/Empcontroller/SaveData',
               method: 'POST',
               headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                         },
               success: function ( fp, o )
               {


               },
               failure: function ( fp, o )
               {

               }
            } );
```

I'm getting the response as true in all  browsers. In `Chrome` its coming into success, But in `Firefox its not.`

Comment: Have you checked with FireBug...?

Comment: And also see the Firefox Console by `Ctrl+Shift+J`

Comment: If the form is multipart, I'm surprised the success message is working at all considering it's probably submitting through an iframe, if extjs 4 has a similar implementation to 3 for handling file data.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding in the dataType param like so:

```
form.submit({
   url: '../api/Empcontroller/SaveData',
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (fp, o) {

   },
   failure: function (fp, o) {

   }
});
```

I have also seen it done this way: (replace **json_data_here** with any data you need to send)

```
form.submit(Ext.Ajax.request({    
    url: '/../api/Empcontroller/SaveData',
    method: 'GET',
    jsonData: json_data_here,
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json' , 'Accept' : 'application/json'}
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there's a FireFox bug that jacks the content-type...

[JQuery - $.ajax ContentType Problem in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179855/jquery-ajax-contenttype-problem-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

try adding anonymous function inside submit instead of a json:

```
form.submit( function(){
               url: '../api/Empcontroller/SaveData',
               method: 'POST',
               headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                         },
               success: function ( fp, o )
               {


               },
               failure: function ( fp, o )
               {

               }
            } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
form.submit( function(){
    url: '../api/Empcontroller/SaveData',method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    success: function (fp, o ){},
    failure: function (fp, o ){}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

hhhmmm. strange.
I think i found the bug.
FireFox doesn't like it when I set the 'asyncron' state on 'false' to tell the script to wait for the reply of the serverrequest.

so instead of 
http.open("GET", destURL, true);
I am using
http.open("GET", destURL, false);

[Firefox dont accept asynchron Option on "false"](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?370372-AJAX-does-not-work-with-FireFox)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the problem. But doesn't file upload require an enctype
Try using

```
enctype = multipart/form-data
```

This might help

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
form.submit( {
               url: '../api/Empcontroller/SaveData',
               method: 'POST',
               headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                         },
               success: function ( fp, o )
               {


               },
               failure: function ( fp, o )
               {

               }
            } );
```

I just changed the content type.