# HTTP: 405 error in IE only. using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http

Hello I have been trying to fix an issue I'm having with IE   It works and passes all the data with Chrome and Firefox but messes up with IE

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
      cache: false
 });

 var dataString = 'firstname=' + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&areacode=' +      areacode + '&phonenumber=' + phonenumber + '&emailaddress=' + emailaddress + '&confirmemail=' + confirmemail + '&password=' + password + '&streetaddress=' + streetaddress + '&streetaddress2=' + streetaddress2 + '&city=' + city + '&state=' + state + '&zipcode=' + zipcode + '&month=' + month + '&day=' + day + '&year=' + year + '&services=' + services + '&agreement=' + agreement; 
  //alert(dataString); 
 // alert(services); 
 //var d = new Date(); 
  $.ajax({
      cache: false, 
         type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.vectorcreditsolutions.com/js/process.php",
        data: dataString,
  //  dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",  
    success: function(ret) {
        window.location.href ="http://www.vectorcreditsolutions.com/thankyou.html";
    }
    });
    return false;
     });
```

and i get an http 405 issue with IE please any input would help 
thank you

Comment: Do you have to use the full URL? Is the script running on a different domain?

Comment: Duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523162/jquery-ajax-get-returns-405-method-not-allowed) You cannot make cross-domain requests using standard ajax

Comment: Does it work if you switch method to GET? also, what version of IE are you using? (IE6 has several known issues).

Comment: @pastor: Question states that everything works in Chrome and Firefox, so cross-domain permissions issues seem unlikely, though the code would benefit from relative paths (/js/process.php)

Comment: The 405 error may indicate that you need to use a "GET" request instead of "POST" - have you tried this?

Comment: I tried using the get method now and the http 405 error is gone now

Answer (score 3):

Your param format seems unusual, I would avoid using & for a post request

Try this

```
   data: { 
        'firstname': firstname, 
        'lastname': lastname,
         .....
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer, but seems plausible to me.